# C++ Skips a line of output/input and goes straight to next input

Tags: visual-c++

```
string fullname, empid;
double hours, pay, fedrate, staterate, medicare = 1.5, socialtax = 6.2, overtime, overtimepay;
int option;

cout.precision(2);
cout.setf(ios::fixed, ios::floatfield);
cout.setf(ios::showpoint);

cout << "Enter Employee's Full Name: " << endl;
cin >>  fullname;

cout << "Enter Employee's ID: " << endl;
cin >> empid;

cout << "Enter Hours Worked: " << endl;
cin >> hours;
hours = fabs(hours);

cout << "Enter Pay Rate: " << endl;
cin >> pay;
pay = fabs(pay);

cout << "Enter Fed Tax Rate: " << endl;
cin >> fedrate;
fedrate = fabs(fedrate);

cout << "Enter State Tax Rate: " << endl;
cin >> staterate;
staterate = fabs(staterate);
```

After inputing a name for fullname it skips the employee id and goes straight into asking for hours worked. Do I have to use getline to fix that or did i do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  See here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

"However, cin extraction always considers spaces (whitespaces, tabs, new-line...) as terminating the value being extracted, and thus extracting a string means to always extract a single word, not a phrase or an entire sentence.

To get an entire line from cin, there exists a function, called getline, that takes the stream (cin) as first argument, and the string variable as second. For example:"